# Number of partition of $[1,m]$ of cardinality $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Given an integer $m \geq 1$, let $\pi_{m, n}$ the set of partition $\pi$ of $[1,m] = \{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $|\pi|$ equal $n$.

I am interested in the cardinality of $\pi_{m, n} $.

For example let $m = 2$. Then $\pi_{2,2} = \{ [\{1\},\{2\}] \}$, $\pi_{2,1} = \{ [\{1,2\}]\}$

Thus $|\pi_{2,2}|=|\pi_{2,1}|=1$.

Let $m = 3$. Then

$\pi_{3,3} = \{ [\{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}] \}$

$\pi_{3,2} = \{ [\{1,2\}, \{3\}], [\{1,3\},\{2\}], [\{3,2\}, \{1\}]\}$

$\pi_{3,1} = \{ [\{1,2, 3\}]$

Of cardinality 1,3, and 1.

I have never encountered $\pi_{m, n} $. Is there a name for this problem? Are there any nice properties of $|\pi_{m, n}|$? Ideally I need non asymptotic lower and upper bound of $|\pi_{m, n}|$.

I apologize if the problem is not well formulated. I am not used to combinatorics.

Thanks,

Edit : context.

If it could help, I need to control :

$$\sum_{n=1}^m |\pi_{m, n}| (-1)^n (n-1)! q^n$$
for $0 \leq q \leq 1$.

Comment: I think here you can find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) The generating function, properties etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the relation with my problem. With the notation of Wikipedia $p(n)$ takes only one argument but $\pi_{m, n}$ takes two.

Comment: I am sorry if you are talking about some other numbers. I am fuzzy.

Comment: @Arthur sorry for not being clear. Where I am not consistent? The first number is $m$, for the set $\{1, \dots, m\}$ and the second is $n$ for the cardinality of the partition. Thus $n \leq m$.

Comment: I found a youtube video of Prof. Doug about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyjsnFtdmsM

Comment: @jvc You're right. I am apparently not reading properly.

Comment: @BobDobbs it seems to be the same problem indeed.

Comment: The Stirling numbers of the second kind!

Comment: @BobDobbs the video proves a nice relation : $\pi_{m, n} = \pi_{m-1, n-1} + n \pi_{m-1, n}$ wich can be helpful. What do you mean about Stirling numbers?

Comment: @BobDobbs that was exactly what I was looking for! The Wikipedia page provides few useful bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define functions $$F_m(q)=\sum_{n=1}^mS(m,n)(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n$$ where $S(m,n)=\pi_{m,n}$ the traditional notation for the Stirling numbers of the second kind (which I am not familiar with).

Then by using the identity $S(m,n)=S(m-1,n-1)+nS(m-1,n)$, we get
$$\begin{align}
F_m(q)&=\sum_{n=1}^mS(m-1,n-1)(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n+\sum_{n=1}^mS(m-1,n)(-1)^nn!q^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}S(m-1,n)(-1)^{n+1}n!q^{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}S(m-1,n)(-1)^nn!q^n\\
&=-q^2F'_{m-1}(q)+qF'_{m-1}(q)\\
&=(q-q^2)F'_{m-1}(q).
\end{align}$$
I found it [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html): Equation $(17)$. Let $G_m(q)=(-1)^m\text{Li}_{1-m}(1-\frac1q)$. Then, this function satisfies the same equation: $G_m(q)=(q-q^2)G'_{m-1}(q)$. So,
$$F_m(q)=(-1)^m\text{Li}_{1-m}(1-\frac1q).$$

Comment: Perfect! I didn't expected such a simple expression. I didn't see the derivative of $F$. Thanks.

Comment: Really? Is it correct number? I can't believe.

Comment: I think the terms $n=m$ is missing, but the idea of seeing the derivative of $F$ is great and I think I can solve my problem with that

Comment: What are we calculating here? Is there a theory connected with?

Comment: I wonder if there is a combinatoric theory to explain what we observed. My problem comes from stochastic geometry and is related to cumulant of determinantal point process.

Comment: Thanks for acceptence but I couldn't solve this question. I am trying to correct my solution and understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $m\in\mathbb N$. By definition, $\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|$ counts the number of partitions $\pi$ of $\{1,\dots,m\}$ with $\left|\pi\right|=n$ ($1\leq n\leq m$). The sum of these numbers
$$\left|\pi_{m,1}\right|+\left|\pi_{m,2}\right|+\cdots+\left|\pi_{m,m}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|$$
then counts the total number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,m\}$. Since this number is precisely the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_m$, we have the following identity:
$$B_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|$$
This gives us crude upper and lower bounds for $\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n$:
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n\right| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^m\left|\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n\right|\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(n-1)!|q|^n\\
&\leq\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(n-1)!\text{ (because }0\leq q\leq 1\text{)}\\
&\leq\sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(m-1)!\text{ (since }n\leq m\text{)}\\
&=(m-1)!B_m
\end{align*}
$$\implies -(m-1)!B_m\leq \sum_{n=1}^m\left|\pi_{m,n}\right|(-1)^n(n-1)!q^n\leq (m-1)B_m$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  the relation is helpful. The bound is good but I would like to keep $q$ as much as possible and take profit of the $(-1)^n$. $q$ is the small parameter in my problem.